# jQuery - Only change for clicked element, not all with the same class

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

The code in the HTML/PHP section is pulled from a database in a while query, so the classes are repeated multiple times throughout the document. When I click on `.up img`, it changes all of the elements on the page with that class. I know I can use `$(this).`, but I'm not sure how that will work for the `$('.down img').` element, since it isn't the object being clicked. I was thinking it may be possible to use the unique `mod` attribute to identify it?

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div class="up"><img src="img/up-g.png" mod="<?=$row_mod['id']; ?>" /></div>
<div class="result"><?php echo votes_total($row_mod['id']); ?></div>
<div class="down"><img src="img/dw-g.png" mod="<?=$row_mod['id']; ?>"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.up img').click( function(){
            var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');
            $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
                console.log(o);
                $('.up img').attr("src","img/up.png");
                $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw-g.png");
            }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: You posted the same question few minutes back .. why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with `this`, and then you navigate to the sibling:

```
$(function() {
    $('.up img').click( function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var postDataUp = $this.attr('mod');
            $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
                console.log(o);
                $this.attr("src","img/up.png");
                $this.closest('.up').nextAll('.down').first().find('img').attr("src","img/dw-g.png");
            }, 'json');
    });
});
```

...and similarly for the `down` button. The long line for that would be `prevAll` rather than `nextAll`:

```
$this.closest('.down').prevAll('.up').first().find('img').attr("src","img/up-g.png");
```

Now, if these are in a container where they're the only `.up` and `.down` (a table row, say, where they're the only ones in *that* row but of course there are others in other rows), it's a bit easier:

```
// The up case
$this.closest('.container').find('.down img').attr("src","img/dw-g.png");

// The down case
$this.closest('.container').find('.up img').attr("src","img/up-g.png");
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('.up img').click( function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var postDataUp = $this.attr('mod');
        $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
            console.log(o);
            $this.attr("src","img/up.png");
            $this.parent().next().next().find("img").attr("src","img/dw-g.png");
        }, 'json');
});
$('.down img').click( function(){
        var postDataDw = $(this).attr('mod');
        $.post('/votePost.php', {varDw: postDataDw}, function(o){
            console.log(o);
            $this.attr("src","img/dw.png");
            $this.parent().next().next().find("img").attr("src","img/up-g.png");
        }, 'json');
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
$(function() {
    $('.up img').click( function(){
            var postDataUp = $(this).attr('mod');
            $(this).attr('submitting', 'true');
            $.post('/votePost.php', {varUp: postDataUp}, function(o){
                console.log(o);
                $('.up img[submitting="true"]').attr("src","img/up.png");
                $('.down img').attr("src","img/dw-g.png");
            }, 'json');
    });
    $('.down img').click( function(){
            var postDataDw = $(this).attr('mod');
            $.post('/votePost.php', {varDw: postDataDw}, function(o){
                console.log(o);
                $(this).attr("src","img/dw.png");
                $('.up img').attr("src","img/up-g.png");
            }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Edit: Try with a flag

Comment: it will still change all up img when clickning on down and vice versa

Comment: `this` won't be what you think it is in the `$.post` callback, and this still processes *all* `.up img` / `.down img`, just not quite as often.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi added the flag check now